# How can I return an array from function and use it's elements as a JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I don't know why but for some reason I can't return an array from the function and so I can't use it as a JSX. Can you explain me how can I do that? or I would be very happy if you'll show me the solution. I just need to print objects as a text from filteredArr array. I'm new to react and looks like everything is not same in react and javascript.
Here's my code:

```js
const payloadURL = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";
const usePeopleData = (filterParams) => {
  fetch(payloadURL)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    let result = data.results;

    // To put every element as an object in array
    let arr = [];
    for (let i in result) {
      let obj = {
        name: result[i].name,
        mass: result[i].mass,
        height: result[i].height,
        gender: result[i].gender
      }
      arr.push(obj);
    }
    let condition = (prop) => prop.height > filterParams.minHeight && prop.gender === filterParams.gender ? true : false;
    let filteredArr = arr.filter((person) => condition(person));
    console.log(filteredArr);
    return filteredArr;
  });
};

const filterPeopleParams = { gender: "male", minHeight: 130 };

function App() {
usePeopleData(filterPeopleParams);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <label>
          Mission name: <input />
        </label>
      </div>
      <h3>People</h3>
      <div>
        <p>/* NEED TEXT HERE */</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
App();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first be carefull in Naming the methods(usePeopleData is detected to be a react customhook! have a look at customhooks naming). then you need to be more deep in react concepts like, declaring a var in state, and calling the api inside useEffect cyclehook and setting the data in state, them showing the result in render.

check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-cannon-2vrfs?file=/src/App.js

`````
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [missionName, setMissionName] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const geteopleData = (filterParams) => {
    const payloadURL = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";
    fetch(payloadURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        let result = data.results;

        // To put every element as an object in array
        let arr = [];
        for (let i in result) {
          let obj = {
            name: result[i].name,
            mass: result[i].mass,
            height: result[i].height,
            gender: result[i].gender
          };
          arr.push(obj);
        }
        let condition = (prop) =>
          prop.height > filterParams.minHeight &&
          prop.gender === filterParams.gender
            ? true
            : false;
        let filteredArr = arr.filter((person) => condition(person));
        console.log("filteredArr: ", filteredArr);
        setList(filteredArr);
        // return filteredArr;
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let filterPeopleParams = { gender: "male", minHeight: 130 };
    geteopleData(filterPeopleParams);
  }, [missionName]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <label>
            Mission name:{" "}
            <input
              value={missionName}
              onChange={(e) => setMissionName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <h3>People</h3>
        <div>
          {list.map((item) => {
            return <p>{item.name}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


````
`````